# How can I use built in Community Component in my own custom component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community

More specifically in my community site I would like to include the community "Follow" button in my own component.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rss_user_profile_follow_button_napili.htm&type=5

I want to do this because I don't want to show the follow button all the time.  I want to control it with some additional logic, and I would rather not try to write my own follow button.  There has got to be a way to use the built in one.

Comment: If the component is not documented, it’s next to impossible to know if there is one. You can check your orgs auradocs for available components

Comment: You cannot do that